# if corto en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

En una pregunta que hice en la página me pasaron el siguiente código:

```
punct_signs = [".", ",", "?", "¿", "!", "¡", "(", ")","«","»" ]
text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs else " " for letter in text)
```

Investigando un poco encontré que esa manera de escribir el condicional `if` se llama `if corto` u `operador ternario` si mal no recuerdo, pero intente escribir

```
text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs and not in names and letter.isdigit()==False else " " for letter in text)
```

Siendo la variable `name` una lista que contiene objetos al igual que `punct_signs` pero me marca que el segundo `in`, el que pertenece a `names`, está mal, o sea me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
   text = "".join(letter if letter not in punct_signs and not in names and letter.isdigit()==False else " " for letter in text)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

¿Por qué pasa eso? no puedo hacer que compruebe si está en 2 listas a la vez?
hay alguna página en donde pueda leer más al respecto acerca del **if corto**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error es porque no pones un valor para buscar en "`names`", solo pones `and ??? not in names`

Lo que debería ser es:

```
text = "".join(letter if (letter not in punct_signs) and (letter not in names) and (letter.isdigit()==False) else " " for letter in text)
```

Puse unos paréntesis en las condiciones para que se vea menos confuso.

Ahora bien, el "*if rápido*" debería ser eso mismo, una instrucción que evalúe condiciones sencillas en una sola línea. Como ese es un `if` más complejo, recomiendo que uses la forma tradicional, ya que en el futuro sería más fácil de mantener el código.

Answer (score 4):

Además de la respuesta que te ha dado aeportugal, en la que te explica por qué estaba mal tu expresión, puedes hacer lo siguiente, que además deja más legible el `if` corto (puesto que ya estaba quedando demasiado "largo" ;-))

La idea es, combinar en una sola lista todos los caracteres "prohibidos", que serían los signos de puntuación, los nombres en `names` y los dígitos. Estos últimos los tienes en `string.digits`. Entonces:

```
import string
prohibidos = punct_signs + names + list(string.digits)

text = "".join(letter if letter not in prohibidos else " " for letter in text)
```

Si prefieres hacer un `if` convencional, tendrás que "desenrollar" la list-comprehension en un bucle normal, y hacer algo como lo siguiente (aprovecho para evaluar la condición contraria, que queda más legible, creo yo):

```
letters_to_join = []
for letter in text:
    if letter in punct_signs or letter in names or letter.isDigit():
       letters_to_join.append(" ")
    else:
       letters_to_join.append(letter)
text = "".join(letters_to_join)
```

pero en mi opinión es más legible la primera opción que te di (aunque puede parecer cuestión de gustos, lo cierto es que no solo son menos líneas de código, sino que son más claras en cuanto a la intención).